# How can I expand my ext4 filesystem after transfering via dd

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi, gparted

I have transferred the whole 64 gb sd-card to a 128 gb sd card. the 64gb sd card is from a Raspberry Pi 4 and contained 5 partitions. I used this command: `dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p of=/dev/sdb` after the process finished I inserted the 128gb sd card and the Raspberry is working fine. However, there are now 64gb of "unallocated" disk space on the sd card.

My guess was to expand the partition, which I attempted using gparted. But I cannot resize the partition as the option to do so is greyed out. I also tried this command `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p7` - `mmcblk0p7` being the root partition - which has this output: `The filesystem is already 15500800 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!`

How can I expand the root partition to use the as yet unallocated diskspace?

```
#fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 119.1 GiB, 127865454592 bytes, 249737216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb134d0fd


Device         Boot  Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192    137215    129024   63M  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      137216 124735487 124598272 59.4G  5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5      139264    204797     65534   32M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p6      204800    729085    524286  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p7      729088 124735487 124006400 59.1G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Did you try to extend it on other machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the commands needed :

```
echo ", +" | sfdisk --force -N 2 /dev/mmcblk0 # Extend the extended partition to maximum
echo ", +" | sfdisk --force -N 7 /dev/mmcblk0 # Extend the partition p7 to maximum
```

Then run resize2fs

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sfdisk.8.html

Do a full backup, and verify it, before you run those commands.

Comment: thank you! I tried to understand what the commands do. `--force` disables some checking. But how does `-N` extend the partition to maximum? I can't seem to comprehend that from the text in the manpages.

Comment: Yes, you are right, --force **Disable all consistency checking**.
-N specify partition number. The plus in ", +" say maximum

Comment: " '+' can be used instead of a number to enlarge the partition as much as possible." Ok, found it, now I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`mmcblk0p7` is contained inside `mmcblk0p2` (the extended partition) and, as you can see, the end sector of p2 is the same as p7 (`124735487`).

Extend your extended partition first (p2), then you will have space to extend p7.

Comment: Additionally, you may consider creating a new primary partition and use `/etc/fstab` to mount it to the root partition in a specific location. Downside of the alternative is that if you'd want to use, say, 80GB for a particular data structure/tree, you would have to split it up among two different filesystems. So in such a case you might even decide to *shrink* p7 to create a new partition beyond the 60GB in size. Finally, there is the pre-creation of partitions and using a tool like `cp` or `rsync` to copy the *contents* of the filesystems rather than the filesystems/partitions themselves.